# Core Data search second level objects (category of item)

Tags: objective-c, search, core-data, nspredicate

My core data system uses items that have a single category set (for example item.category = `<Category object>`) and I want to use my NSPredicate to search through them.

Currently sending a search string "string" will only match items that contain that string, but I want categories to match as well. Is it possible to set up an NSPredicate that uses this nested structure or a custom selector to tell the system if the search string matches?

In pseudo-code, here is what I'm looking for:

```
if (item.title contains "search string" OR item.category.title contains "search string")
    object matches search string
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, KVC (Key Value Coding) allows you to chain as deep as you want through entities.  However be warned that the predicate gets more expensive the more entities you join together:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title == %@ || category.title == %@", title, title];
```

This is assuming you are running the predicate against the "item" entity table.